# How to deploy reports on Development server in SSRS ,I got below Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

> The specified report server url  could not be found.verify that syntax of the URL and the report server exists

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd get better results for your question if you showed us the (anonymized) URL.

Still, I suspect that you're providing an invalid URL. The URL (`TargetServerURL`) needs to be something like `http://localhost/reportserver` and the report path (`TargetServerURL`) can be anything, like `MyReports` or `Accounting`.

Comment: I Have done Same thing like http://localhost/reportserver ,Again i got same error.Shall i need any permission to deploy SSRS reports  on Development server through my local Pc?

Comment: What happens when you address the report server URL you use in the Internet Explorer? Do you see the Report Server user interface? If not, there may be problems like: Report Server not running, IIS not running, port not open in firewall, etc., etc. If there's a problem with the user rights, Report Server will tell you so.